# Wrapping Json fields into instance variable of a pojo

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson2

i am trying to map certain json fields to a class instance variable.

My sample **Person** class looks like:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private Address address;

   //many more fields 

   //getters and setters
}
```

The sample **Address** class is:

```
public class Address {
   private String street;
   private String city;
   //many more fields 

   // getters and setters
}
```

The json object to be deserialized to my Person class doesn't contain "address" field. It looks like:

```
{
"name":"Alexander",
"street":"abc 12",
"city":"London"
}
```

Is there a way to deserialize the json to the Person pojo where the Address fields are also mapped properly?

I have used a custom Address deserializer as mentioned in so many posts here. However, it's not being called as the Json object doesn't contain "address" field.

I had resolved this problem by mapping each field manually using JsonNode, however in my real project, it's not a nice solution.

Is there any work around for such problem using jackson? 
Plus if this question has been asked before then apologies on my behalf as as i have intensively searched for the solution and might have not seen it yet. .

Comment: you can create super class of this one that contains no address and use converter. Avoid manual exercising.

Comment: Is it a homework or what? There is an almost identical question, [asked just a few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386011/how-to-transform-a-flat-json-to-hierarchical-java-class/54387958)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@JsonUnwrapped` annotation was introduced for this problem. Model:

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Address address;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"name\":\"Alexander\",\"street\":\"abc 12\",\"city\":\"London\"}";
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Person.class));
```

Prints:

```
Person{name='Alexander', address=Address{street='abc 12', city='London'}}
```

For more info read:

1. [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)
2. [Annotation Type JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html)
3. [Jackson JSON - Using @JsonUnwrapped to serialize/deserialize properties as flattening data structure](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-unwrapped.html)

Comment: The downvote is my bad. It happened accidentally as i wanted to upvote it. Now, i can't upvote it as long as the @Michał Ziober doesn't edit it. Message i am getting is "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." My bad. As soon as it will be edited i will change it

Comment: I have added one more extra URL. You can upvote it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really have a deserialization problem here but rather a general Java problem: how to make sure the `address` field always contains a value. All you need to do is either assign `address` to a default value in the `Person` constructor, or generate and assign a default value for `address` in the `Person.getAddress` method.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem so that it is about flat Json that has all `Address` fields at the same level as `Person`. Even if it is not exactly so this might help you. `JsonDeserializer` will do fine but you need to apply it to `Person` because it is the level where all the fields are.

So like this:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Person> {

    // need to use separate ObjectMapper to prevent recursion
    // this om will not be registered with this custom deserializer
    private final ObjectMapper om;
    {
        om = new ObjectMapper();
        // this is needed because flat json contains unknown fields
        // for both types.
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public Person deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // make a string of json tree so not any particular object
        String json = om.readTree(parser).toString();
        // deserialize it as person (ignoring unknown fields)
        Person person = om.readValue(json, Person.class);
        // set address deserializing it from teh same string, same manner
        person.setAddress(om.readValue(json, Address.class));
        return person;
    }

}
```

Of course this is not the only way and might not have the best performance but it is only about how you do the deserialization in your custom deserializer. If your `Person` & `Address` objects are havin like 10 fields each using this should not be a problem.

**Update**

I think that in your case - based on your example data - [Michał Ziober's
 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373637/6413377) might be the best but if you need any more complex handling than plain unwrapping for your data you just need to deserialize `Person` class somehow like I presented.