# Spring Boot - Json to Java Nested Object

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

In my spring boot application, I get a request with flat json like this.

```
{
   "firstname" : "a",
   "lastname" : "b",
   "street": "non main st",
   "city": "NY"
}
```

I want to map to Java object like this.

```
class Person {
   String firstname;
   String lastname;
   Address address;
}

class Address {
    String street;
    String city;
}
```

Is this possible?

---

Do note that this is for my spring-boot application which automatically deserialize this. I do not use Object Mapper directly.

---

Controller:

My REST controller is nothing special.

```
@RestController
public class TestController{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public void justPrint(@RequestBody Person person){
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrapping Json fields into instance variable of a pojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370637/wrapping-json-fields-into-instance-variable-of-a-pojo)

Comment: @MichałZiober, I am afraid it is not. I have updated

Comment: Behind the scene `ObjectMapper` is used anyway. `SpringBoot` to deserialise `JSON` payload to `Java` `POJO` model uses by default `Jackson` and it's classes set. Related link contains just an example with `ObjectMapper` to check it out with copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [@JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) on your `Address` field:

```
class Person {
   String firstname;
   String lastname;
   @JsonUnwrapped
   Address address;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Although `GET` can work as well, you should really use `POST` or `PUT` HTTP method mapping in your controller e.g. here I'm gonna use `@PostMapping`:

```
@RestController
public class TestController{
    @PostMapping("/")
    public void justPrint(@RequestBody Person person){
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

And you should send the data when running `curl` command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "street": "1st Str.", "city": "London"}' http://localhost:8080/
```

Here I am assuming that your service is running on port **8080**. And one more thing, if you do not have `toString()` implemented for the `Person` class, do write one, since only class name would be displayed with `System.out.println`.

Comment: Does it work in Spring boot without using object mapper? I do not think so

Comment: You don't need to use `ObjectMapper` directly. For each request, Spring will try to find the appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` to use for read and write of JSON content. In this case it will use the [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html), which will do all serialization/deserialization for you.

Comment: Hm, strange since this should work. How is your controller and method for recieving this JSON payload defined? Can you update your question with controller code

Comment: I added the controller.